# How do you use jquery sortable to sort table cells in all the table's rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wanna make a sortable table and using jquery sortable I can either sort the rows in the tables or the cells in a row, but I can't move a cell between rows.
How can I do that?

For example.
In here: http://jsfiddle.net/dado_eyad/mKaFe/2/

I wanna move `Second row: 2` to the place of `First row: 1`

Answer (score 6):

I have a CSS trick to let sortable table cells
act like the sortable grid sample:
https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

the Javascript part it as simple as:

```
$('table').sortable({
    items: 'td', 
});
```

The point is to make use of the CSS `display` property.

when you drag a cell from row2 to row1,
row1 would become 4 cells, row2 only have 2 cells left,
and the width would be shrinked to match the table width.

If we use tr `display: inline;` in the stylesheet,
let `td` display as `inline-block`.
The layout rendering would behave more like a list of inline-blocks.
Ignoring the restrictions of tr.

For a live demo, see the fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/elin/4Q6Qn/

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your `< tr >`'s in a `< tbody >` and change the your code to:

```
  $("table tbody tr").sortable({
    items: 'td',
  }).disableSelection();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/142/)**

You have to specify the container that contains the elements you want to be sortable not the actual elements.

#### I wanna move Second row: 2 to the place of First row: 1

```
 $("table tbody").sortable({
    items: 'tr',
  }).disableSelection();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/mKaFe/1/)**

Comment: They are in a `<tbody>` tag and your code makes the first `<td>` draggable but it's still moving the whole row `<tr>` with it.

Comment: I know how to make the cell sortable inside the row. My question is sorting cells between rows.
For Example, I want to put `Six` in the first row in your example.

Comment: @dado_eyad check my demo and answer

Comment: This is moving the whole row. I only wanna move the `<td>`

Answer (score 3):

Just use connectWith parameter and some script:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5nx7exh/2/)

```
$('table tr').sortable({
items: 'td',
connectWith:'table tr',
stop:function(e,prop){
  var id = prop.item;
  const colNum=3;
  $('table tr').not(':last').each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    if($this.children().length<colNum)
    {
      $this.append($this.next().children(':first'));
    }
    else if($this.children().length>colNum)
    {
      $this.next().prepend($this.children(':last'));
    }
  });}
```

})

Comment: The only demo that works in 2022

Comment: For any developers who come across this in the future: this solution allows cells to be moved anywhere in the table and maintains the constant number of columns. Eddie Lin's solution works, but it allows table cells to be added on to the ends of rows, creating uneven columns.

Answer (score -1):

Simple sortable table in javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap extras: Table sort indicator</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

   <style>
   /* Table sort indicators */

th.sortable {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

th.sortable::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0dc";
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  color: #999;
}

th.sortable.asc::after {
  content: "\f0d8";
}

th.sortable.desc::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
}

th.sortable:hover::after {
  color: #333;
}

/* Heading styles */

h1.age-header {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
h2.page-header {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  line-height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 > .divider:before,
h2 > .divider:before,
h3 > .divider:before,
h4 > .divider:before,
h5 > .divider:before,
h6 > .divider:before,
.h1 > .divider:before,
.h2 > .divider:before,
.h3 > .divider:before,
.h4 > .divider:before,
.h5 > .divider:before,
.h6 > .divider:before {
  color: #777;
  content: "\0223E\0020";
}
   </style>
<script>

function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>


</head>

<body>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th class="sortable" onclick="sortTable(0)">Field 1</th>
        <th class="sortable" onclick="sortTable(1)">Field 2</th>
        <th class="sortable" onclick="sortTable(2)">Field 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Data 3</td><td>Data 6</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js">
    /*
    Use this below code in a separated file(index.js)

    var $sortable = $('.sortable');

$sortable.on('click', function(){

  var $this = $(this);
  var asc = $this.hasClass('asc');
  var desc = $this.hasClass('desc');
  $sortable.removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
  if (desc || (!asc && !desc)) {
    $this.addClass('asc');
  } else {
    $this.addClass('desc');
  }

});
    */
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```